# Doctrine fixtures won't get loaded in given order, instead, they get loaded in alphabetical order

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

As far as I know, fixtures will be loaded in given order, based on the value returned in `getOrder()` method of each fixture files. [Sharing Objects between Fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures). For some reason, doctrine tries to load fixtures below in alphabetical order (class name) instead.

In example below, it has to load in Student, Subject and StudentSubject order however, it tries to load in Student, StudentSubject and Subject which causes problem because StudentSubject cannot exist before Student and Subject. Association: `Student (1 -> N) StudentSubject (N <- 1) Subject`

Any reason why this is happening?

```
class StudentFixtures extends AbstractFixture implements FixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        ......
        $this->addReference('student-1', $student);
        ......
    }

    public function getOrder() { return 1; }
}

class SubjectFixtures extends AbstractFixture implements FixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        ......
        $this->addReference('subject-1', $subject);
        ......
    }

    public function getOrder() { return 2; }
}

class StudetSubjectFixtures extends AbstractFixture implements FixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        ......
        $student = $this->getReference('student-1');
        $subject = $this->getReference('subject-1');
        ......
    }

    public function getOrder() { return 3; }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Bc-MacBook-Pro:sport bc$ app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction --no-debug
  > purging database
  > loading Football\FrontendBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\StudentFixtures
  > loading Football\FrontendBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\StudentSubjectFixtures
 [OutOfBoundsException]              
  Reference to: (mba) does not exist
```

**composer.json**

```
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",

    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.0",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.1.1"
},
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Replace instances of `FixtureInterface` with `OrderedFixtureInterface`

for example:

`use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;`

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is about order, it might be more easier to think about dependencies and let the code figure out the order, e.g.

```php
class StudentSubjectFixtures extends AbstractFixture implements DependentFixtureInterface

    public function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [StudentFixtures::class, SubjectFixtures::class];
    }
```